# Removing duplicate data from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-loc

I am trying to retrive data every few hours and since the data will have a lot of duplicate data I will remove all the duplicate data which has the same date and keep the first instance.
Here is my code to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
import os
from os import path
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sys

while True:
    if path.exists('stockdata.csv') == True:
        data1 = pd.read_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ', index_col=0)
        ts = TimeSeries(key='1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y', output_format='pandas')
        data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol = 'spy', interval='1min', outputsize='full')
        data = data.rename(columns={ '1. open':'Open','2. high': 'High','3. low': 'Low', '4. close':'Close', '5. volume': 'Volume'})
        data1 = data1.append(data)
        data1 = data1.loc[data1.duplicated(keep='first'), :] # This should remove the rows which have duplicate dates
        data1.to_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ')
        break
    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame()
        data1.to_csv('stockdata.csv', sep= ' ')
```

`data1 = data1.loc[data1.duplicated(keep='first'), :]` This should remove 1 instance of the the rows which have duplicate dates but if i run the code 2 times i still have double the rows.

As a example to demonstrate what i am trying to accomplish:

```
"2019-11-20 09:57:00" 311.405 311.44 311.4 311.41 42081.0
"2019-11-20 09:56:00" 311.38 311.425 311.33 311.41 63551.0
"2019-11-20 09:55:00" 311.34 311.4525 311.34 311.39 98011.0
"2019-11-20 09:53:00" 311.55 311.59 311.46 311.4832 125541.0
"2019-11-20 09:57:00" 311.405 311.44 311.4 311.41 42081.0
"2019-11-20 09:56:00" 311.38 311.425 311.33 311.41 63551.0
"2019-11-20 09:55:00" 311.34 311.4525 311.34 311.39 98011.0
"2019-11-20 09:54:00" 311.49 311.51 311.33 311.33 85857.0
"2019-11-20 09:53:00" 311.55 311.59 311.46 311.4832 125541.0
```

As you can see what is happening is data is being appended thus as in the example above it is being pasted 2 times. There will however be a new unique entry when new data is appended. So here i am trying to remove all duplicates to keep just new entries.

if i run `data1.loc[data1.index.duplicated(keep = 'last'), :]` in a different cell i get :
[image]

All the entries are removed.

Comment: you really need to post a snippet of code that anyone can copy and paste to see your actual vs expected output .... no one can duplicate your code since it uses data not included ... **just include a small dataframe or series and what you get vs what you expect** .... this wall of text is hard to read through and grok

Comment: @JoranBeasley The reason why i have not included a snippet of the dataframe is because in its current form it contains over 3731 row and some are duplicates.

Comment: so make one that looks like `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]` instead and use that to demonstrate the problem  ...  surely you dont need 4000 rows nor the real data entries to show the problem

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following DataFrame (2 rows for each day):

```
Dat               Val
2019-06-03 12:07  20
2019-06-03 16:10  23
2019-06-04 10:04  30
2019-06-04 14:47  32
2019-06-06 11:42  49
2019-06-06 18:17  51
```

To leave only the first reading from each day, you can:

- group by *Dat* column with *D* frequency,
- print only the first row from each group,
- drop rows from dates where there was no input row (option).

The code to do it is:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Dat', freq='D')).first().dropna()
```

The result is:

```
             Val
Dat             
2019-06-03  20.0
2019-06-04  30.0
2019-06-06  49.0
```

If your input column is of *integer* type and you want to keep it
as *integer*, you can add `.astype(int)` to the above code.

## Edit

If the above solution computes too slow, try:

```
df.groupby(df.Dat.dt.date).first().drop(columns='Dat')
```

This time no "empty dates" are inserted, so there is no need to *dropna*.

Comment: using groupby to drop duplicates is **much** more expensive computationally than using pandas `drop_duplicates `